# opam install Curl failed

Tags: ocaml, opam

newbie question:

I have opam version 2.0.5 installed on windows 10 (using cygwin).

I tried to opam install utop

all but 3 out of the 22 packages installed fine, so i don't think it is network issues. 
What can I do about the 3 that don't install, and why is this happening? (I have tried on two seperate days).

```
<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[camomile.1.0.2] found in cache
[charInfo_width.1.1.0] found in cache
[cppo.1.6.6] found in cache
[dune.2.1.2] found in cache
[dune-configurator.2.1.2] found in cache
[dune-private-libs.2.1.2] found in cache
[lambda-term.2.0.3] found in cache
[lwt.5.1.1] found in cache
[lwt_log.1.1.1] found in cache
[lwt_react.1.1.3] found in cache
[mmap.1.1.0] found in cache
[ocamlbuild.0.14.0] found in cache
[ocplib-endian.1.0] found in cache
[result.1.4] found in cache
[WARNING] ocamlfind.1.8.1: download of
          http://download.camlcity.org/download/findlib-1.8.1.tar.gz failed
          (http://download.camlcity.org/download/findlib-1.8.1.tar.gz (Curl
          failed: "D:\\cygwin64\\bin\\curl.exe --write-out %{http_code}\\n
          --retry 3 --retry-delay 2 --user-agent opam/2.0.5 -L -o
          D:/cygwin64/home/ysg4206/.opam/ocaml-variants.4.07.1+mingw64c/.opam-sw
itch/sources/ocamlfind.1.8.1/findlib-1.8.1.tar.gz.part
          http://download.camlcity.org/download/findlib-1.8.1.tar.gz" exited
          with code 28)), trying mirror
[utop.2.4.3] found in cachep] [topkg.1.0.1: http]
Processing 21/22: [ocamlfind.1.8.1: http] [topkg.1.0.1: htt
[zed.2.0.4] found in cache
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - ocamlfind.1.8.1: Curl failed
          - react.1.2.1: Curl failed
          - topkg.1.0.1: Curl failed


ysg4206@YSG4206 ~
$ opam --version
2.0.5
```

Comment: You have a connectivity issue (curl code 28 - means time out). Check your internet connection and/or firewall settings.

Comment: But all the other downloads worked. And I am on a corporate network.And when I use my browser to download (chrome) at: http://download.camlcity.org/download/findlib-1.8.1.tar.gz I get the GZ file. Is there a way I can manually tell opam this file, given I have it downloaded to a folder?

Comment: well, your browser is probably configured differently than `curl` and may use a proxy. Other packages that you were able to download probably came from a different location, e.g., GitHub, or used a different protocol, e.g., `https`. Most likely, you corporate network does not allow you to download files using the `http` protocol, which actually makes sense. Honestly, I'm surprised that `ocamlfind` is only available via `http`.

Comment: Hint, you can also try to use `OPAMFETCH` to specify the download command, you specify it using the `download-command` variable in the opam configuration. You can also ask for help in the opam github's page, on the OCaml discuss forum (https://discuss.ocaml.org/) or on the discord channel  (https://discord.gg/MaJWj2j).
Just SO is a little bit different site, and not about your corporate network setup :)

Comment: @ivg I concur about discord, discuss, etc. But since you are giving me good info. Can I follow up? Are there not three files that are failing? If so, is there some way of manually finding what they urls are and then manually putting those where opam will find it (or is that too hard). Git I am using the same HTTP_PROXY for https and http, and that is working for git to github and other programs, It would be nice to no exactly what the url for react, topkg and ocamlfind are and use fiddler to figure out what the corporate firewall is doing (I expect ZERO help from our I.T.)

Comment: $ opam install cmdliner
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install cmdliner 1.0.4

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - cmdliner.1.0.4: Curl failed

Comment: you will find the same me in discord or discuss, no worries :) All three packages are using `http` (which is quite uncommon nowadays, and unsafe), it might be a coincidence, but my guess it the crux of the problem. You can find the source url of a package here (https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ocamlfind/) (just substitute the name), see the source field. And it looks like that your curl is not using a proxy at all.

Comment: I moved the question to discuss, and gave you more information why CURL must be using our proxy.